# MQ consumer ACK (MQFB_COA)

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have a JMS consumer application with IBM MQ and Websphere. in the provider application side, it requires a "ACK (MQFB_COA)" with (JMS_IBM_FEEDBACK=259) for trigger the next process.

Although, I didn't implement any code to handle such ACK, it is still able be received in provider side at one of our testing environments. However, the ACK is missing at the other environment. The most strange is that the consumer application, MQ server and WAS setting are totally identical.

My questions:

1. Is this ACK sent by MQ server (Query Manager) or WAS automatically?
2. If Q1 is Yes, is it depended on the header of received Query?
3. Is the "JMS_IBM_FEEDBACK=259" included in ACK (MQFB_COA)?
4. Or should I implement a function to handle it with JMS in application?

Comment: COA is handled by the queue manager but requires the correct permission for the user listed in the MQMD of the message in addition to the reporting option for COA

Comment: What platform does the queue manager run on.  What is the version.   Have you checked the error logs  for not authorized errors?